# Using simulator for turtlebot before actual robot testing

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am looking to carry out testing through simulation for my Turtlebot3 robot, before I run the packages for my actual robot, just to see if any issues arise etc. I have the packages ready to go (launch file, python files etc.).

I just have a few questions:

1. How do I bring up a simulator of my Turtlebot Waffle-pi version? (Do I use Rviz?). I should know this, but my training so far has just been with the Turtlebot and having the movement of the robot shown on Rviz, I have not actually simulated any movement as of yet.
2. If I have a map of my lab, can I upload that to the simulation to carry out the simulated testing? Or can I only use pre-constructed maps from ROS libraries? I only need a 2D map for now and I have multiple maps built using my Turtlebot3 and SLAM.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I am using ROS Kinetic and Ubuntu 16.04LTS, along with the Turtlebot3 Waffle-pi version.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/359916/using-simulator-for-turtlebot-before-actual-robot-testing/) by [jimc91](https://answers.ros.org/users/45049/jimc91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2020-08-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest working through:

1. [Robotis e-manual on the Turtlebot 3](https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/overview/).
2. [ROS Navigation 2 tutorials](https://navigation.ros.org/tutorials/index.html)

Questions you pose should be covered. If not, you can try to narrow the scope of your questions, so the community can help as appropriate.

---

Originally posted by [surfertas](https://answers.ros.org/users/27828/surfertas/) with karma: 265 on 2020-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0